# How to open a new url in current tab? - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried a lot of different methods. But all of them lead to the url opening in a new tab. Using javascript, how can i do this?

(no jQuery please, this is a school project and we haven't had jQuery as a lesson yet)

this is the function i'm working with:

```
function myFunction() {
            window.open('project.html', 'toolbar=0, location="_self", menubar=0');
            target = "_self";
            }
```

Comment: window.location.href = " "; // location

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`location` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
location = ...;
```